# Calling a variable from another class that's contained within a for loop

Tags: python, django

variable from another class that's contained within a for loop.
Problem calling it

see my example

Tried to move code around and making global variables but did not work.

```
import requests

class Values:

    def get_crypto_data_dict(self):
        usd_url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?" \
                  "vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1" \
                  "&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h"
        gbp_url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?" \
                  "vs_currency=gbp&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1" \
                  "&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h"

        previous_request = None

        crypto_dict = None
        crypto_dict = dict()

        requests1 = requests.get(usd_url)
        results1 = requests1.json()

        requests2 = requests.get(gbp_url)
        results2 = requests2.json()

        for i in range(0, 250):
            crypto_dict[results1[i]['id']] = {
                'coin_name': results1[i]['name'],
                'changes': results1[i]['price_change_percentage_24h'],
                'usd': results1[i]['current_price'],
                'gbp': results2[i]['current_price']
            }


    # print(crypto_dict['bitcoin']['coin_name']) = will show coin name


class Portfolio(Values):

    def __init__(self, coin, holdings):
        self.coin = coin
        self.holdings = holdings

    def Get_User_Coins(self):
        continues = True
        coins_holdings = {}
        while (continues == False):
            coin = input("Enter the Coin Name i.e(Bitcoin(BTC) is bitcoin): ")
            holdings = input("Enter the  amount of holdings of the coin: ")
            print("\n")
            # Attatch to the current user


    def Pull_Coin_Dat(Values):
    # 'burst': {'coin_name': 'Burst', 'changes': 10.4028903177228, 'usd': 0.00425861382756581, 'gbp': 0.00329588603402332}}
    print()


    lol = Portfolio('xrp', 600)
    lol.Pull_Coin_Dat()
```

To be able to call crypto_dict located in Values class from Pull_Coin_Dat function.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the `crypto_dict` dictionary from the `get_crypto_data_dict()` as:

```
return crypto_dict
```

Then call the function inside `Pull_Coin_Dat(self)` as

```
called_crypto_dict = self.get_crypto_data_dict()
```

Then you can access any data you want from the `called_crypto_dict`

To avoid the indentation error you need to indent the function call as:

```
def Pull_Coin_Dat(Values):
    # 'burst': {'coin_name': 'Burst', 'changes': 10.4028903177228, 'usd': 0.00425861382756581, 'gbp': 0.00329588603402332}}
    called_crypto_dict = self.get_crypto_data_dict()
    print()
```

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/BfdQj3k.png) 

I have tried your suggestion but I am getting an error. Please take a look at the screenshot I linked.

Comment: You need to provide a tab for the called_crypto_dict = ..... The error is because python requires the block inside the function to be indented